# Using Assert Java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble understanding how assert in java works.
I want to make so that if the assert is not true then the test should fail. The following example should returns false but the test does not fail. What I'm I missing?

Example:

```
package test;

public class tests {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tests s = new tests();
        s.approve(500);
    }
    public   boolean approve(int age)
    {
        assert (age < 60) :"Test Failed" ;
        if (age > 100)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `-ea` passed to the VM? By default assertions are disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable assertions with the `-ea` flag.

You probably don't want to use `assert` though, but a proper testing framework that has its own assertion methods.

Answer (score 2):

Condition `age < 60` is true for `age` equal to 50. Therefore the condition will succeed and the assert will not fail.

Assert will fail when the condition is `false`.

Comment: Updated, but it still does not fail

Answer (score 0):

The thing to understand about asserts as that they're intended only for the development phase. They're not a part of the solution you're delivering to your client, they're a way of catching bugs early in your development phase. That's why you turn them off in production.